# Lucene query parsing behaviour - joining query parts with AND

Tags: java, search, lucene

Let's say we have a Lucene index having few documents indexed using `StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET`. A user is issuing two queries:

- `foo:bar`
- `baz:"there is"`

Let's assume that the first query yields some results because there are documents matching that query.

The second query yields 0 results. The reason for this is because when `baz:"there is"` is parsed, it ends up as a void query as both *there* and *is* are stopwords (technically speaking, this is converted to an empty `BooleanQuery` having no clauses). So far so good.

However, any of the following combined queries

- `+foo:bar +baz:"there is"`
- `foo:bar AND baz:"there is"`

behave exactly the same way as query `+foo:bar`, that is, brings back some results - all despite the second `AND` part which yields no results.

One might argue that when ANDing, both conditions have to be met, but they aren't.

It seems contradictory as an atomic query component has different impact on the overall query depending on the context. Is there any logical explanation for this? Can this be addressed in any way, preferably without writing own `QueryAnalyzer`? Can this be classified as a Lucene bug?

If this makes any difference, observed behaviour happens under Lucene v3.0.2.

This question was also posted on [Lucene Java users mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-java-user/201105.mbox/%3CBANLkTi=xjCgcy6xcaM3-yQZRmRP+TcexiA@mail.gmail.com%3E), no answers came so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erick Ericksson from Lucene mailing list [answered](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-java-user/201105.mbox/%3CBANLkTikD39vCoiqZN2Z2y=r7tezgd+Cptw@mail.gmail.com%3E) one part of this question:

> But imagine the impact of what you're
>   requesting. If all stop words get
>   removed, then no query would ever
>   match yours. Which would be very
>   counter-intuitive IMO. Your users have
>   no clue that you've removed stopwords,
>   so they'll sit there saying "Look, I
>   KNOW that "bar" was in foo and I KNOW
>   that "there is" was in baz, why the
>   heck didn't this cursed system find my
>   doc?

So it looks like the only sensible way is to cease using stopwords or reduce the stopword set.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using the StopAnalyzer if you want to be able to search for phrases like "there is". StopAnalyzer is essentially a lossy optimization method and unless you are indexing huge text documents it's probably not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is perfectly fine. You can imagine the result for an empty query being the whole document collection. However, this result is omitted for practical reasons. Sone basically you're ANDing with superset not an empty set.

E: You can think of it in a way that additional keywords refine the result set. This makes most sense when you take prefix search into account. The shorter your prefix is, the more matches there are. The most extreme case would be the empty query matching the whole document collection

Comment: But in this case, `baz:"there is"` should then also bring back the whole collection, right? - but it isn't, and that's the point. I disagree with refinement argument, because refinement is something totally different from AND.

Comment: It should, but it can't. "Bring back the whole collection" will kill performance for any decent collection. For the same reason many search applications enforce a minimum size of prefixes.

Bringing back the whole collection means to take the whole index, and to merge all doclists (and aggregate them and so on). So while baz:"there is" shoould return the whole collection just like the query "", it doesn't because a user never requires this result and its computation is craziely expensive

Comment: I'm afraid I have to disagree again. QueryParser can play smart and convert such a query into MatchAllDocsQuery (which is available by default in Lucene), also it's not the querying but data retrieving that is expensive. What seems most logical to me is not to return any records at all (your answer was suggesting to bring back everything, that's why I asked).